# Angular2 Date format

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am trying to format a date from a datepicker in a angualr 2 service..

date is a string "2010-01-01" and will be formatted to 01/01/2010.. I know I could use pipes but want to figure this out manually..

```
static formatDate(date: string){
    const dateString = date.match(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})$/) ;
    const date_decode = new Date(dateString[3], parseInt(dateString[1]-1), dateString[2]);
  }
```

I am a brand new noob @ angular2 so this its a struggle..

dateString should be an array with data from the regex.. I've tried a few things to initize the array with no luck..  can someone walk me thru this?

Comment: what is the parameter you are getting in `date`? Is it just a string like: "2010-01-01"?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this solution thanks to a co-worker..

```
static formatDate(initialDate: string): string {
    const initialDateParsed = Date.parse(initialDate.replace('-', '/'));
    const newDate = new Date(initialDateParsed);

    if (isNaN(initialDateParsed)) { throw new Error(`Invalid initialDate provided: '${ initialDate }'`); }

    const yyyy = newDate.getFullYear();
    const mm = (`0${ newDate.getMonth() + 1 }`).slice(-2);
    const dd = (`0${ newDate.getDate() }`).slice(-2);

    return `${ dd }/${ mm }/${ yyyy }`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your function **formatDate** param date is "2010-01-01" which is in "YYYY-MM-DD" format then your desired output 01/01/2010 is in "MM/DD/YYYY" format then below is ts function

```
static function formatDate(date){
    const dateString = date.match(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})$/) ;
    const date_decode = new Date(dateString[1], parseInt(dateString[2]-1), dateString[3]); // date_decode = javascript ISO date string
    const formatted_date = date_decode.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
    console.log(formatted_date); // formatted_date = 01/01/2010
  }
```

Here above same code in action in javascript (slightly modified)

```js
function formatDate(date){
    const dateString = date.match(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})$/) ;
    const date_decode = new Date(dateString[1], parseInt(dateString[2]-1), dateString[3]); // date_decode = javascript ISO date string
 const formatted_date = date_decode.toLocaleDateString('en-US'); // remove 'en-US' if you want output in user local format
 console.log(formatted_date); // formatted_date = 01/01/2010
  }
formatDate('2010-04-01');
```